# How to extract the binary files from QT Resource to QT temporary directory

Tags: c++, qt

In order to protect the binary files (*.exe) that my program used, I reference this post ([Adding executables as resources of a Qt application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677846/adding-executables-as-resources-of-a-qt-application)) to import some of binary files into the QT resource file (if there is a better way to protect the binary file, it would be very helpful to know).

I would like to extract the binary files into temporary directory when program runs. I have tried the QFile::copy with QTemporaryFile::createNativeFile, but some errors showing (I am totally new on C++ and QT, sorry for the stupid questions).

[Error Message figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKbsx.png)

QT version is 5.4.2

OS: Win7 64bit

Update@0930 0927 UTC:
Thanks for the comment from @drescherjm, the error is fixed. But another error showing when I try to use below code to copy the file from resource file to C:.

```
QFile f(":/test.exe");
f.copy("C:\\test.exe");
qDebug() << "CopyResult" << f.errorString() ;
```

or

```
QFile::copy(":/test.exe", "C:\\test.exe");
```

and the error message is showing, is it a permission issue?

```
"Cannot create C:\test.exe for output"
```

Comment: Post error messages verbatim as text in your question please.

Comment: ^ And post the code sample as text. No pictures of text please!

Comment: The problem is that you seem to be trying to execute code in the class declaration instead of a class member function.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, you are right, thanks for your comment.

Comment: I believe UAC prevents writing to the root folder of c: on modern windows operating systems.

Comment: ***Update@0930 0927 UTC:*** BTW, You are not supposed to change your topic once a question is asked. You are supposed to ask a single question. StackOverflow is not a user help forum. It is more as a resource of good questions with answers to help future readers. It would be highly unlikely that a future reader to have both different problems at the same time and find this question in a search.

Comment: @drescherjm Got it, thank you so much.